# Whats app share like ubar in android

Tags: java, android, share

I am currently looking to share some content through Whatsapp.
Currently i can share test but how can i share below like ubar.

my current code is this.

```
Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, <content>+"_Shared Via_  *App Name*");
whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
try {
    startActivity(whatsappIntent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        //whatsapp not installed
}
```

[image: Whats app share]

Comment: I think whatsapp adds the preview automatically when it detects a web url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That text is downloaded from the uber website link, that is set in the webpages meta data.

```
 <meta property="og:title" content="FREE UBER RIDE">
 <meta property="og:description" content="Sign up now to claim your free gift from Sanjay (₹ 100 off first ride)*.">
```